# Using "at" to call a delayed process from within a cgi script

Tags: perl, start

Here is a puzzle I hope you can help me with. A client wants to send a welcome letter exactly 47 minutes after a document is uploaded via cgi script.
I wrote a routine to send the letter, and then I attempted to use the Linux "at" command to execute it.

When this didn't work, I set up the following test in the /cgi-bin directory.

---

************  The bottom line is: The "at" command will not work when called by apache. Is there any way around this?

---

Thanks,

Rob Young

```
TEST FILES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

$> cat test1.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
#THIS IS A TEST OF THE "at" LINUX COMMAND WHEN CALLED FROM WITHIN APACHE
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
my @lt=localtime(time()+60);
my $cmd="echo '/path/to/test2.pl' | at $lt[2]:$lt[1]";
print $cmd;
system($cmd);

$> cat test2.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $cmd="echo 'it ran!'>it_ran.txt";
system($cmd);




COMMAND LINE DEMONSTRATION
------------------------------------------------------------------
$> rm it_ran.txt
rm: cannot remove `it_ran.txt': No such file or directory
$> ./test1.pl
Content-type: text/html

echo '/path/to/test2.pl' | at 20:28job 55 at 2011-08-15 20:28
$> atq
55      2011-08-15 20:28 a ryoung
$> date
Mon Aug 15 20:27:11 CDT 2011
$> cat it_rat.txt
cat: it_rat.txt: No such file or directory
$> date
Mon Aug 15 20:28:01 CDT 2011
$> cat it_ran.txt
it ran!


APACHE DEMONSTRATION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Then I call the same script by browsing to http://www.MYSERVER.com/cgi-bin/test1.pl
[browser output:
                  echo '/path/to/test2.pl' | at 20:30
]

$> date
Mon Aug 15 20:30:40 CDT 2011
$> cat it_ran.txt
cat: it_ran.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4):

Specify the full path to `at` in the script. Not to mention your `it_ran.txt` file. How do have any idea whatsoever where that file is supposed to be deposited? It's probably trying to get written to the root directory and failing.

You should use **error checking**. Check the result code of the system command or at itself.

Programs and calls return errors to help you handle exceptions appropriately.